# for loop doesn't stop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have the following code, and it never stops. It never evaluates the next condition once it has finished with exporting the file. What am I doing wrong?
I am working on Python 3.x and Windows 10.

```
for maindir, subdirs, shpfiles in os.walk(by_numSegments): # check in the whole folder
    if "poly1000numSeg" in maindir: # check only in the input folder (segment_img)
        if "compactness_1" in maindir: 
            for s, ishp in enumerate(shpfiles):
                input_list = list(filter(lambda mpoly: mpoly.endswith('.shp'), os.listdir(maindir)))
                # list with the first uploaded polygon. In the loop will the following polygons added
                auto_inter = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(os.path.join(maindir, input_list[0]))
                # add the rest of the polygons one by one
                for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
                    mp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(os.path.join(maindir, input_list[i+1]))
                    auto_inter = gpd.overlay(auto_inter, mp, how='intersection')
                # export    
                auto_inter.to_file(os.path.join(src, "compactness_1/numSeg1000_c1.shp"))
        if "compactness10" in maindir: 
            for s, ishp in enumerate(shpfiles):
                input_list = list(filter(lambda mpoly: mpoly.endswith('.shp'), os.listdir(maindir)))
                # list with the first uploaded polygon. In the loop will the following polygons added
                auto_inter = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(os.path.join(maindir, input_list[0]))
                # add the rest of the polygons one by one
                for i in range(len(input_list)-1):
                    mp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(os.path.join(maindir, input_list[i+1]))
                    auto_inter = gpd.overlay(auto_inter, mp, how='intersection')
                # export    
                auto_inter.to_file(os.path.join(src, "compactness10/numSeg1000_c10.shp"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `src` is the same folder you are iterating. You are adding files while iterating the file list.

```
for maindir, subdirs, shpfiles in os.walk(by_numSegments): # check in the whole folder
    if "poly1000numSeg" in maindir: # check only in the input folder (segment_img)
        if "compactness_1" in maindir: 
            for s, ishp in enumerate(shpfiles):
                input_list = list(filter(lambda mpoly: mpoly.endswith('.shp'), os.listdir(maindir)))  # get file list
                ......
                for i in range(len(input_list)-1):  # loop through list
                    .......
                auto_inter.to_file(os.path.join(src, "compactness_1/numSeg1000_c1.shp"))  # create new file
```

Try setting `input_list` before the loop:

```
maindir, subdirs, shpfiles in os.walk(by_numSegments): # check in the whole folder
    if "poly1000numSeg" in maindir: # check only in the input folder (segment_img)
        if "compactness_1" in maindir: 
            input_list = list(filter(lambda mpoly: mpoly.endswith('.shp'), os.listdir(maindir)))  # get file list
            for s, ishp in enumerate(shpfiles):                   
                ......
                for i in range(len(input_list)-1):  # loop through list
                    .......
                auto_inter.to_file(os.path.join(src, "compactness_1/numSeg1000_c1.shp"))  # create new file
```

Comment: thanks, but I didn't understand. What do you suggest?